# Preview Crystal Report on a separate form

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports-xi

I have a form that allows a user to select what report they want to generate. They can also select criteria, select Print, Preview, export, etc.   After the user makes their selections and clicks the "Generate" button, I have a class that creates the report object, loads the report, dataset, and then prints or exports the report.  I created a separate form to preview the report.  When I pass the report object to the preview form, I receive "Invalid Report Source."  The report prints and exports just fine, I just cannot preview the report.  I do not want to duplicate the code in the preview form, I was hoping that I could just pass the report object.  Snippets of my code are below.  Any suggestions?

```
public static class CrystalReportUtilities
{
    private static ReportDocument goReport {get; set;}
    private static string gsReportName { get; set; }
    private static string gsSqlString { get; set; }
    private static object[,] goParameters { get; set; }

    public static void generateReport(parameters...)
    {
      goReport = loadReport();
...
      goReport.SetDataSource(DataTable);
...
      previewReport();


    private static void previewReport()
    {
        CrystalReportPrintPreviewForm loReportPreview = new CrystalReportPrintPreviewForm(goReport);
        loReportPreview.ShowDialog();
    }


public partial class CrystalReportPrintPreviewForm : Form
{
    private ReportDocument goReport;

    public CrystalReportPrintPreviewForm(ReportDocument poReport)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        goReport = poReport;
    }

    private void crystalReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (goReport != null)
            {
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = goReport;  // Receive "Invalid Report Source"
            }
        }
```

Comment: So I changed the Preview Form so that I am no longer passing the report into the form, form the class.  I changed the method in the class to return a ReportDocument after it loads the report. In my form I call that load method and set the DataSource.  Now the form loads, but I get the error message: Method not Found" 'Void CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageRender.set_ExceptionWIndowTitle(System.String)'.   I am now trying to track this down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved.   I am running on a Windows 7, 64 bit OS.  I originally installed Crystal Reports for 64 bit Visual Studio 2010.  It appears that you need both, the 64 bit and 32 bit version of the runtimes, with SP4.